# Deployed Spring boot Application in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Deployed Spring Boot application in tomcat. It has been loaded properly using webservletinitializer.

But After loading it is show exceptions.

```
Mar 20, 2015 11:28:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 20, 2015 11:28:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Mar 20, 2015 11:28:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:721)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:582)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5357)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 20, 2015 11:28:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
```

When I deployed application in tomcat. It is loading two webApplicationInitializer.

```
Mar 20, 2015 11:28:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@17f6f610, com.cpp.ServletInitializer@5694a0ba]
Mar 20, 2015 11:28:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

1. Is exception occuring due to two webApplicationInitializer OR if Not then what might be reason and how can I fix it.
2. Why there are two webapplicationInitializers . What is impact of it ?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file named as application.properties. We need to keep management.port property commented there or keep value as same as post of tomcat.

If management.port value is not equal to tomcat port. Then It tries to run another tomcat with given port. That is reason behind exception.